# Spring Tool Suite with the Google GWT plugin throws errors in Java2HTMLEntityReader

Tags: java, spring, gwt, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I tried to update old project to new version of STS. It mostly worked but for some reason, google plugin - required for the project - throws errors:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
    org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/comment/Java2HTMLEntityReader
```

In the error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2016-03-08 12:39:04.740
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/comment/Java2HTMLEntityReader
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm.views.hierarchical.LogContent.convertToHtmlContent(LogContent.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm.views.hierarchical.LogContent.buildLabelHtml(LogContent.java:332)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm.views.hierarchical.LogContent.updateDetailsPane(LogContent.java:599)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm.views.hierarchical.LogContent.access$4(LogContent.java:568)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm.views.hierarchical.LogContent$4.selectionChanged(LogContent.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2197)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1733)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:388)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm.model.LogContentProvider$2.run(LogContentProvider.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

This is caused by the google GWT plug-in. I installed that plugin using STS welcome page button:

[image: image description]

So I must have the latest version. I tried to request updates, there are no updates reported for that plugin. I can't step away from GWT at this point, so how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of GPE is broken for mars, meaning this exception occurs. In the not too distant future, this will be fixed.

Until then I have a workaround in a fork that will fix this in mars. Download the fork of the GPE plugin here:
http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html

Follow the instructions on the download page.